# Wrong result for filtering by substring

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am creating a filtering input where brings the results according to keyUp. This is what I am doing for filtering, through a Backbone's Collection:

```
var Brand = Backbone.Model;

var Brands = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Brand,
    filterByName: function () {
        return this.filter(function (model) {
            return model.get('name').indexOf('h') > -1;
        });
    }
});

var fiat = new Brand ({ name: 'Fiat' });
var honda = new Brand ({ name: 'Honda' });
var chevrolet = new Brand ({ name: 'Chevrolet' });
var peugeot = new Brand ({ name: 'Peugeot' });
var mitsubishi = new Brand ({ name: 'Mitsubishi' });
var hyundai = new Brand ({ name: 'Hyundai' });

var brands = new Brands ([ fiat, honda, chevrolet, peugeot, mitsubishi, hyundai ]);

console.log(brands.filterByName());
```

> Playground: http://jsfiddle.net/Lgcb0skm/

The point is: when I type `h`, for instance, it brings me only **Mitsubis*h*i** and **C*h*evrolet**, instead of all the possible results, such as ***H*onda**, ***H*yundai**, etc. Why? Suggestions?

Comment: `.get('name').toLowerCase().indexOf('h') > -1`

Comment: Please, turn your comment into an answer to accept. I am too stupid, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer `'H' != 'h'`. You will need to lower case your text string if you want to do case insensitive matches:

```
return this.filter(function (model) {
    return model.get('name').toLowerCase().indexOf('h') > -1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
return model.get('name').toLowerCase().indexOf('h') > -1;
```